# Extracting client specific code. refactoring possibilities required

Tags: java, object-oriented, design-patterns

I am facing a Design problem. I have a set of classes which writes data in `XML`,`JSON` or `HTML` formates for different clients.

I have a class which receives `Data` and a `XML, JSON or HTML writer` as it parameter.

And these Writer have a common Interface, Writer uses the Data to create Data in speficied format. The writes have methods like `writeHead`, `writeBody`, `WriteImages`, `writeFooter`, `writeDescriptions`

Now my problem is that `Descriptions` part of the Documents is very client specific. Only that specific part looks completly different for each client but the rest of the Document is same.

Should I use `writeDescriptions` as a factory which calls clientSpefic `writeDescriptions` function? then I have another problem that I have many different formates like JSON,HTML,XML....

What will be the best possible way to hanlde is sitution?